# xslt grabbing wrong xml info on second loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am converting an xml to a different xml using xslt. I use:

```
<xsl:template match="header">
<header>
        <order><xsl:value-of select="@order"/></order>
    <value><xsl:value-of select="../header"/></value>
</header>
</xsl:template>
```

to grab info that is in the header.

The original header file:

```
<header order="1">blah11111</header>
<header order="2">blah22222</header>
```

What I am getting from this when I do apply templates:

```
<header>
   <order>1</order>
   <value>blah11111</value>
</header>
<header>
   <order>2</order>
   <value>blah11111</value>
</header>
```

What I want:

```
<header>
   <order>1</order>
   <value>blah11111</value>
</header>
<header>
   <order>2</order>
   <value>blah22222</value>
</header>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like your `value` element is not being refreshed from the first read.  That being said, its not looking at the current `header` but instead the first instance of `header`.  One way to verify this is to switch the `header` nodes order and see if the first node is always the value for the `value` element of the 2nd node.

Answer (score 1):

The `select` on your second `xsl:value-of` element is climbing up to the parent and then descending again to get all the `header` elements; `xsl:value-of` then ignores all but the first of these.

If what you want is not the value of the first `header` but the value of the header that you're currently processing, then your `select` attribute is saying the wrong thing.  Try

```
<value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 1.0, when xsl:value-of selects more than one node, it outputs the value of the first and ignores all the others. This behaviour is very error prone, so it is changed in XSLT 2.0 to output all the values - which isn't necessarily what you want, but at least it makes it clear what's going wrong.